# DQL to find all the folders present in a cabinet

Tags: java, dql, documentum

I would like want to fetch all the folders present in all the cabinets using a DQL statement like this

`SELECT object_name, r_object_id, r_folder_path FROM dm_folder WHERE FOLDER(’/Cabinetname’,descend) ORDER BY r_folder_path`

In DQL tester it's giving me response, but when I'm using it in my code I obtain server time out because it's a quite expensive query. Is there any way to resolve the situation and improve the query?

Comment: describe your objective and I'm sure you'll find smarter way to achieve it

Comment: well all i want is to create a tree like structure available for the user with the cabinets,folders,sub folders on which he is having access. For that i am trying to first retrieve the folders and then create a tree structure with the help of attribute ""ancestor ids".

Comment: It is not recommended to select everything within a folder in this way, because it will take unreasonably long time to retrieve the results. Even for regular file systems on a local computer this can be very slow (just try it out).

Instead, I suggest fetching only the next level that you are interested in, each time you click a plus sign (or similar) to expand that folder.

(Remove "descend" from the query.)